# Display properties of a country, from online service

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, vue.js

I'm currently learning Vue JS and I made a simple app that pulls information from API and displays facts about a country given a 2-letter country code. I'm looking for feedback on how to improve the code. I'd appreciate any feedback. Many thanks.

This is my app.vue

````
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      userinput: "",
      country: {
        name: "",
        capital: "",
        currency: "",
        phone: "",
        emoji: "",
        languages: [],
        continent: "",
      },
      properties: { demonym: "", area: "", timezones: [], population: "" },
    };
  },
  computed: {
    className: function () {
      if (this.country.continent) {
        if (this.country.continent.name == "Europe") return "europe";
        else if (this.country.continent.name == "Asia") return "asia";
        else if (this.country.continent.name == "Antarctica")
          return "antarctica";
        else if (this.country.continent.name == "Oceania") return "oceania";
        else if (this.country.continent.name == "Africa") return "africa";
      }
      return "";
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onEnter: function () {
      if (this.userinput !== "") {
        let body = {
          query: `
          query($code: ID!) {
            country(code: $code) {
              name
              capital
              currency
              phone
              emoji
              languages {name}
              continent {name}
            }}`,
          variables: { code: this.userinput },
        };
        let options = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
        axios
          .all([
            axios.post(
              "https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql",
              body,
              options
            ),
            axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/" + this.userinput),
          ])
          .then(
            axios.spread((data1, data2) => {
              /*console.log(res.data);*/
              let countryName = data1.data.data.country.name;
              let capital = data1.data.data.country.capital;
              let currency = data1.data.data.country.currency;
              let phone = data1.data.data.country.phone;
              let emoji = data1.data.data.country.emoji;
              let languages = data1.data.data.country.languages;
              let continent = data1.data.data.country.continent;

              this.country.name = countryName == null ? "" : countryName;
              this.country.capital = capital == null ? "" : capital;
              this.country.currency = currency == null ? "" : currency;
              this.country.phone = phone == null ? "" : phone;
              this.country.emoji = emoji == null ? "" : emoji;
              this.country.languages = languages.length == 0 ? "" : languages;
              this.country.continent = continent == null ? "" : continent;

              let demonym = data2.data.demonym;
              let area = data2.data.area;
              let timezones = data2.data.timezones;
              let population = data2.data.population;

              this.properties.demonym = demonym == null ? "" : demonym;
              this.properties.area = area == null ? "" : area;
              this.properties.timezones =
                timezones.length == 0 ? "" : timezones;
              this.properties.population = population == null ? "" : population;

              console.log(this.country.name);
              console.log(this.country.capital);
              console.log(this.country.currency);
              console.log(this.country.phone);
              console.log(this.country.emoji);
              console.log(this.country.languages);
              console.log(this.country.continent);
              console.log(this.properties.demonym);
              console.log(this.properties.area);
              console.log(this.properties.timezones);
              console.log(this.properties.population);
            })
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data.error);
          });
      }
    },
    nameWithComma(index, name, languageslist) {
      if (index !== languageslist.length - 1) {
        return name.concat(",").trim();
      } else {
        return name;
      }
    },
    convertToLineBreak(txt) {
      if (!txt) {
        return txt.replace(txt, "<br>");
      }
      return txt;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app" :class="className">
    <main>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="search-bar"
          placeholder="Enter a two-letter country code..."
          v-model="userinput"
          @keyup.enter="onEnter"
        />
      </div>

      <div v-if="country.name != ''">
        <div class="countryname-box">
          <div class="name">{{ country.name }}</div>
          <div class="continent">
            {{ country.continent.name }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="emoji-box">
          <div class="emoji">
            {{ country.emoji }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="countryinfo-box">
          <div class="left-container">
            <div class="second-half">
              <p class="bold">Currency:</p>
              <p class="bold">Timezone:</p>
              <p class="bold">Language(s):</p>
              <p class="bold">Capital:</p>
              <p class="bold">Area:</p>
              <p class="bold">Demonym:</p>
              <p class="bold">Population:</p>
              <p class="bold">Call Code:</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="right-container" style="white-space: pre">
            <p>{{ convertToLineBreak(country.currency) }}</p>
            <div
              class="textinline"
              v-for="(item, index) in properties.timezones"
              :key="index"
            >
              {{ nameWithComma(index, item, properties.timezones) }}
            </div>
            <br />
            <div
              class="textinline"
              v-for="(item, index) in country.languages"
              :key="index"
            >
              {{ nameWithComma(index, item.name, country.languages) }}
            </div>
            <p>{{ country.capital }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.area }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.demonym }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.population }}</p>
            <p>{{ country.phone }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>
```
````

Comment: is there css or a styling framework?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding Vue this code looks quite good. I do however have some issues with the general JavaScript and HTML.

---

I'm not a big fan of using empty strings for missing data. `null` or `undefined` would be a better. For one it simplifies reading the data from the API (more on that later).

---

The calculation of the class name could be much simpler. At the very least use a local variable instead of repeating `this.country.continent.name`. But the chain of `if`s is unnecessary. In the simplest case, just convert the continent name to lower case, (optionally checking it against a list of allowed names). Also the use of newer JavaScript features such as [optional chaining (`?.`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) can simplify it even more:

```
computed: { 
   className() { // Abbreviated syntax for functions in object literals
      return this.country.continent?.name?.toLowerCase();
   }
}
```

---

The assignment of the data to your data objects can also be simpified by using modern technics such as [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (and dropping the empty strings for missing data). Also use `const` instead of `let` for variables that don't change.

```
axios.spread((trevorbladesData, restcountriesData) => { // Better parameter names
   const {name, capital, currency, phone, emoji, languages, continent} = trevorbladesData.data.data.country;
   this country = {name, capital, currency, phone, emoji, languages, continent};

   // similar for `properties`
}
```

---

There are better ways to add commas between items than `nameWithComma`.

For example, put the comma into the template. BTW, instead of a `div` with `textinline` just use a natural inline element such as `span`, or if you don't really need the elements at all, just use `template`. Additionally there should be a surrounding element:

```
<div>
  <template
    v-for="(item, index) in properties.timezones"
    :key="index"
  >
    <template v-if="index !== 0">, </template>{{ item }}
  </template>
</div>
```

Another way whould be be to use `computed` to generate the comma separated list. This is probably the easiest:

```
computed: {
   // ... more computed functions
   timezones() {
      return properties.timezones.join(", ");
   }
}
```

and just use

```
<div>{{ timezones }}</div>
```

in the template.

---

`convertToLineBreak` is a very strange way to replace an empty string with a line break. Why not just:

```
convertToLineBreak(txt) {
   return txt || "<br>";
}
```

Aside from that, the way you are using it will just literally display `<br>`.

But you shouldn't do this at all anyway because:

---

The way you are displaying the data in the HTML is terribly broken. It is not accessable (screen readers will first read all the captions and the the data), it requires extra work to makr sure there is always a line (using `pre` and `<br>`s) and will break if the data unexpectedly is longer than one line.

In HTML it is important to use the [proper semantic markup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics#semantics_in_html). In your case you should be using a [description list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) (CSS can be used to have the items appear in a single line) or simply a table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Currency:</th>
    <td>{{ country.currency }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Timezone:</th>
    <td>{{ timezones }}</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- etc. -->
</table>
```

Comment: The OP's code didn't appear to handle cases for the other continents (i.e. "South America" and "North America") but those are possible values so simply returning the lower case of those values would be different than what the OPs code returns.

Comment: tables aren't the most friendly for screen readers either.

Comment: @depperm But they are much better than two unrelated elements. At the very least the entries will be read in the correct order. And there are additional ARIA attributes that can be added to enhance the accessibility.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I did mention that the name could be validated against a list. Or the function could extended to for example replace spaces with hyphens.

Answer (score 4):

**Simplify**

Computed `className` is just lowercase continent name

```
className: function () {
  if (this.country.continent) {
    return this.country.continent.name.toLowerCase()
  }
  return ''
}
```

As you don't resuse any of the variables in axios spread (`let countryName = data1.data.data.country.name;`) and null displays empty, these lines can be reduced to:

```
this.country.name = data1.data.data.country.name;
this.country.capital = data1.data.data.country.capital;
this.country.currency = data1.data.data.country.currency;
this.country.phone = data1.data.data.country.phone;
this.country.emoji = data1.data.data.country.emoji;
this.country.languages = data1.data.data.country.languages.map(l=>l.name);
this.country.continent = data1.data.data.country.continent;

this.properties.demonym = data2.data.demonym;
this.properties.area = data2.data.area;
this.properties.timezones = data2.data.timezones;
this.properties.population = data2.data.population;
```

`languages` is a list of objects, so you can map it now

`query` doesn't actually need to be multiline (though this may reduce readability)

```
query: 'query($code: ID!) {country(code: $code) { name capital currency phone emoji languages {name} continent {name}}}'
```

I believe the currency display doesn't need to replace with line break, if it isn't specified the `p` tag will be empty. The two `div` with `v-for` that call `nameWithComma` should probably be replaced with a `p` and a `join` (the css isn't specified, but the method still seems overly complicated)

```
<p>{{ country.currency }}</p>
<p>{{ properties.timezones.join() }}</p>
<p>{{ country.languages.join() }}</p>
```

**Improve Input**

Some users may not know the 2 country code of the country they want. Having a `select` or autocomplete input would probably improve UX (user experience). Minimum effort would be to set `maxlength="2"` of `input`

**Improve Error Output**

If a user currently enters an invalid code nothing in the display specifies something went wrong. Using a `select` would remove half of these (invalid input), but if the api is down, letting the user know something went wrong would be useful. Add prop `error`

```
<div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
<div v-else>
...
     axios.spread((data1, data2) => {
          /*console.log(res.data);*/
          this.error = ''
      ....
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.data.error, error);
        this.error = error.message
      });
```

**Full code:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app" :class="className">
    <main>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="search-bar"
          maxlength="2"
          placeholder="Enter a two-letter country code..."
          v-model="userinput"
          @keyup.enter="onEnter"
        />
      </div>
      <div v-if="error">{{ error }}</div>
      <div v-else>
        <div class="countryname-box">
          <div class="name">{{ country.name }}</div>
          <div class="continent">
            {{ country.continent.name }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="emoji-box">
          <div class="emoji">
            {{ country.emoji }}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="countryinfo-box">
          <div class="left-container">
            <div class="second-half">
              <p class="bold">Currency:</p>
              <p class="bold">Timezone:</p>
              <p class="bold">Language(s):</p>
              <p class="bold">Capital:</p>
              <p class="bold">Area:</p>
              <p class="bold">Demonym:</p>
              <p class="bold">Population:</p>
              <p class="bold">Call Code:</p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="right-container" style="white-space: pre">
            <p>{{ country.currency }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.timezones.join() }}</p>
            <p>{{ country.languages.join() }}</p>
            <p>{{ country.capital }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.area }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.demonym }}</p>
            <p>{{ properties.population }}</p>
            <p>{{ country.phone }}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      userinput: "",
      country: {
        name: "",
        capital: "",
        currency: "",
        phone: "",
        emoji: "",
        languages: [],
        continent: "",
      },
      properties: { demonym: "", area: "", timezones: [], population: "" },
      error: ''
    };
  },
  computed: {
    className: function () {
      if (this.country.continent) {
        return this.country.continent.name.toLowerCase();
      }
      return ''
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onEnter: function () {
      if (this.userinput !== "") {
        let body = {
          query: 'query($code: ID!) {country(code: $code) { name capital currency phone emoji languages {name} continent {name}}}',
          variables: { code: this.userinput },
        };
        let options = { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } };
        axios
          .all([
            axios.post(
              "https://countries.trevorblades.com/graphql",
              body,
              options
            ),
            axios.get("https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/" + this.userinput),
          ])
          .then(
            axios.spread((data1, data2) => {
              /*console.log(res.data);*/
              this.error = ''

              this.country.name = data1.data.data.country.name;
              this.country.capital = data1.data.data.country.capital;
              this.country.currency = data1.data.data.country.currency;
              this.country.phone = data1.data.data.country.phone;
              this.country.emoji = data1.data.data.country.emoji;
              this.country.languages = data1.data.data.country.languages.map(l=>l.name);
              this.country.continent = data1.data.data.country.continent;

              this.properties.demonym = data2.data.demonym;
              this.properties.area = data2.data.area;
              this.properties.timezones = data2.data.timezones;
              this.properties.population = data2.data.population;
            })
          )
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.response.data.error);
            this.error = error.message
          });
      }
    }
  },
};
</script>

<style>
.left-container {
  float: left;
}
.right-container {
  float: right;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The OP's code didn't appear to handle cases for the other continents (i.e. "South America" and "North America") but those are possible values so simply returning the lower case of those values would be different than what the OPs code returns.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ yes/no, its a class name, if OP applies a class without a style its basically the same as not having a class at all.